# Functional change needed for "see own leads" option in Odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-view

when i used this domain rulein "Personal leads" rule under "see own leads" group, so that users can also see those leads that they follow with leads they own i got an error,

domai rule :

['|',('user_id','=',user.id),('user_id','=',user.message_follower_ids)]

error:

"Invalid value %r in domain term %r" % (right, leaf)

AssertionError: Invalid value mail.followers(10,) in domain term ('user_id', '=', mail.followers(10,))

Comment: May we see what code/config you have, and what you have tried? We encourage new posters to try what they want first, prior to asking the community.

Comment: i tried a lot of domain rule options and tried to access the ids of followers of a lead

Comment: when i used this domain rulein "Personal leads" rule under "see own leads" group, so that users can also see those leads that they follow with leads they own i got an error,

domai rule :

['|',('user_id','=',user.id),('user_id','=',user.message_follower_ids)]



error:

"Invalid value %r in domain term %r" % (right, leaf)

AssertionError: Invalid value mail.followers(10,) in domain term ('user_id', '=', mail.followers(10,))

Comment: Please add that information to your question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** You should search with the current user's partner in the models followers, like:

`['|', ('user_id', '=', user.id), ('message_partner_ids', 'in', [user.partner_id.id])]`

Interesting example is one of Odoos default rules for project tasks "Project/Task: portal users: (portal and colleagues following) or (followers and following)"

Comment: but "in" operator is used with list,

Comment: and "user.message_follower_ids.ids" is not a list

Comment: it shows this error:raise ValueError("Invalid field %r in leaf %r" % (left, str(leaf)))
ValueError: Invalid field 'user_id' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('user_id', '=', 8) on mail_followers (ctx: )>"

Comment: after using this rule,opening a lead still gives me error

Comment: error:     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/osv/expression.py", line 844, in parse
    raise ValueError("Invalid field %r in leaf %r" % (left, str(leaf)))
ValueError: Invalid field 'user_id' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('user_id', '=', 10) on mail_followers (ctx: )>"

Comment: i am using this domain rule in "personal lead" record rule : ['|',('user_id','=',user.id),('message_partner_ids','child_of',[user.commercial_partner_id.id])]

Answer (score 1):

You're having this error `ValueError: Invalid field 'user_id' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('user_id', '=', 10) on mail_followers (ctx: )>"` because the mail.followers model does not have a user_id field.

The domain that you're using is one that is used on crm.lead or sale.order (where user_id indicates the seller). Like @CZoellner points it out, you should read the examples he mentions.

Fields you filter records on must exist on the model.